# MailKit The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: c#, mailkit

I have this method for testing the MailKit Send() function but I am getting an error when I call the Connect() method. "The hostname could not be parsed". I added a simple System.Net.Mail Send() call and it functions as expected using the same hostname. MailKit however fails. I tried a solution of replacing the hostname with the IP address but I get a certificate error going that route. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

*[somedomain] is fictional, the real domain has been replaced*

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@somedomain.com">
    <network host="mailrelay.somedomain.com" userName="" password="" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>


    private static void SendMail()
    {
        Configuration oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var mailSettings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup) oConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings");

        if (mailSettings == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException($"object mailSettings cannot be null");
        }

        using (var msClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
        {
            msClient.Send("fromemail@somedomain.com", "toemail@somedomain.com", "Important Test", "Test Email Process");
        }

        //return;

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var message = EmailGenerator.CreateSimpleMessage();
            client.Connect(mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host, mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port);
            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the real value of `somedomain` matters. Does it have a special character which is subject to PunyCode? Did you accidentally copy/paste an invisible character? May two letters have been replaced by a ligature? Stuff like that goes unnoticed.

Comment: @ThomasWeller. No, the only thing I modified here is the client's real domain.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I got it. I ran an additional test using Uri.TryCreate() and it too failed. It appears that System.Net.Mail does not care about a [protocol] where TryCreate() and MailKit.Send() does. After adding the line Uri.TryCreate($"https://{mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host}", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out Uri uri); and adding the [protocol] https:// before the stored mailhost I was able to successfully send.

Comment: Whaaaaat??? This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you will either need to store the https:// on the web config section with the hostname or modify it in code. System.Net.Mail does not care but I was able to replicate the error using Uri.TryCreate().

```
Uri.TryCreate($"https://{mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host}", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out Uri uri);
```